# How can I handle SIGINT trap with a user prompt in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, signals, interrupt-handling, sigint

I am trying to handle `SIGINT` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - interrupt in such a way that if a user accidentally presses `ctrl-c`, he is prompted with a message: *"Do you wish to quit?(y/n)"*. If he enters yes, then exit the script. If no, then continue from where ever the interrupt occurred. Basically, I need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to work similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> -`SIGTSTP` - but in a slightly different way. I have tried various ways to achieve this but I didn't get the expected results. Below are few scenario which I tried.

**Case:1**

**Script : play.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
function stop()
{
while true; do 
    read -rep $'\nDo you wish to stop playing?(y/n)' yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "Thanks for playing !!!"; exit 1;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer (y/n)";;
    esac
done
} 
trap 'stop' SIGINT 
echo "going to sleep"
for i in {1..100}
do
  echo "$i"
  sleep 3   
done
echo "end of sleep"
```

When I run the above script, I get the expected results.

**Output:**

```
    $ play.sh 
    going to sleep
    1
    ^C
    Do you wish to stop playing?(y/n)y
    Thanks for playing !!!

    $ play.sh 
    going to sleep
    1
    2
    ^C
    Do you wish to stop playing?(y/n)n
    3
    4
    ^C
    Do you wish to stop playing?(y/n)y
    Thanks for playing !!! 
    $
```

**Case:2**
I moved the for loop to a new script *loop.sh*, thus play.sh becomes the parent process and loop.sh the child process.

**Script : play.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
function stop()
{
while true; do 
    read -rep $'\nDo you wish to stop playing?(y/n)' yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "Thanks for playing !!!"; exit 1;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer (y/n)";;
    esac
done
}
trap 'stop' SIGINT 
loop.sh
```

**Script : loop.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "going to sleep"
for i in {1..100}
do
  echo "$i"
  sleep 3   
done
echo "end of sleep"
```

Output in this case is not as expected.

**Output:**

```
$ play.sh 
going to sleep
1
2
^C
Do you wish to stop playing?(y/n)y
Thanks for playing !!!

$ play.sh 
going to sleep
1
2
3
4
^C
Do you wish to stop playing?(y/n)n
$
```

I understand that when a process receives a `SIGINT` signal, it propagates the signal to all the child processes, thus my 2nd case is failing. Is there any way that I can avoid `SIGINT` being propagated to child processes and thus make the *loop.sh* work exactly the way it worked in the 1st case?

**Note:** *This is just an example of my actual application.
The application I am working on has several child scripts in play.sh and loop.sh. I should make sure that the application on receiving SIGINT, should not terminate but it should prompt the user with a message.*

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240602/4667

Answer (score 1):

In your `play.sh` don't call up a new script, but source it like this:

```
source ./loop.sh
```

I'd say due to non spawning a new subshell for the script, the program flow is continued when you exit the trap. If you call a new script, the trap is propagated to the subshell but it can't return if you exit the subshell.